# Google Drive/SDK API Project deleted

Tags: api, project, google-drive-api

I created an API project using the Google API console. This project uses the Google Drive API and Drive SDK for an Android app. After the project is created, my app can access the folders and files in my Google account. However, after two may be three weeks, that API project is deleted by Google (I think). Consequently, my app stopped working. I have to undelete the project so that my app works again, but sometimes the undelete doesn't work and I have to create a new project with a new API key. 
Please let me know what I need to do to keep the project active.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We don't delete projects, certainly if there was an issue with yours we would have discussed it with you before taking action. Sorry you went through this. I will investigate just to be sure it was nothing we did on our end.